# Elevator Timing Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**"Suppose a building has 15 floors. A person works on the 11th floor of this building. The elevator travels endlessly between all floors (1,2,3,..., 14,15,14,...,3,2,1) instead of stopping on a floor where the button has been pressed. Assume that the amount of time required to load and unload passengers is minimal compared to the actual trip time. The person always wonders why, when he is about to leave his office at 6 p.m., the lift goes up before stopping at his floor most of the time. Provide a valid explanation for this phenomenon in terms of probability."**

This question arrived on my university quiz, and I am unsure if my answer was correct.
What I did was
[Probability Distribution Table taking Random Variable X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLBKR.png)

I took a Probability Distribution table where I compared all the values for **P(x<11)** and **P(x>11)** while taking the whole of Time period, **T = the whole time of elevator passing from floor 1 to back to floor 1.**

> N.P: Sorry my last question here did not mention how I approached it. This
> is my first post here so I didn't know how this site worked.

Comment: The lift goes down before reaching the person's floor only if it is at floors greater than $12$ at that given time. You can quickly check that the elevator spends most of its time below the $11$th floor.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track but you need to consider that the elevator doesn't magically reappear at $1$ after it has gone to $15$. So if you think about which sequence of numbers will be repeated forever it looks like this:

$$1,2,3,...,13,14,15,14,13,...,3,2$$

Note that it does not end in $1$ because now you can copy that sequence and attach it to the end to continue the sequence. So the numbers $2$ to $14$ show up twice as often as $1$ and $15$. What does the distribution look like then? And what do $P(X>11)$ and $P(X<11)$ look like?